# UICollectionView not rendering cells - no code only storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am experimenting with UICollectionView and am only using Storyboard - no code at all. I set the number of items to 3 and gave each cell a different color and reuse identifier in the storyboard. Yet the CollectionView (pinkish background) is shown but no cells are shown. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance
-SR

[image: Screenshot vs Storyboard]

[image: No code in viewcontroller]

Comment: How are your cells setup? Are they static cells or dynamic cells?

Comment: Static - using storyboard. There is no code in the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

`UICollectionView` doesn't support static content layouts.

## Discussion

But there is a way to simulate it through code. I recommend [this](https://robkerr.com/how-to-create-a-static-uicollectionview-af8ce3bf07ac) great article.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any code in your ViewController.swift. You can add something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

      var menuItems = ["Aap","Koe","Vis","Paard", "Leeuw", "Varken"]

      @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
      }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if let c = cell as? AangepasteCollectionViewCell {
          c.cellLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].capitalized
        }

        return cell

      }
    }
```

For this example you have to give the collection cell the name `cell` in the atribute inspector